# Copy a mesh at the location of each vertex of another mesh or curve

Tags: modifiers, dupli-groups

I have a mesh (e.g. a fish). I would like to duplicate this mesh at the location of every vertices of another mesh.

In my example, this means that I would like the fish to be duplicated at the location of each vertex of a mesh. I would then edit this mesh to easily control the location of all fishes.

I looked at modifiers (and in particular Array), but couldn't find it. I wonder if this could be achieve using particles. Maybe a dupli-group? (I haven't tried this last one)

Comment: Using Hair and verts to emit Object > Fish in Question might be the start of a solution. Do the duplicate fish need to exhibit specific motion?

Comment: In this case, no, the fish does not need to emit motion.

Comment: The description of the "dupli-group" tag here says: "Dupli-groups duplicate an object at each face, vertex or edge of a mesh." so that's promising too

Answer (score 2):

In order to copy a mesh (A) on the vertex location of another mesh (B), you have to select B, click on context object , select instancing and click verts. Then click A first and shift click B and press Ctrl + P to parent, a menu should pop out and pres object. Now the object A is copied on the vertices of object B. The copied ojects will be oriented on the B's vertices normals.

Comment: "The copied ojects will be oriented on the B's vertices normals" - did you mean that the instanced object copies will be rotated according to the normals of parent's vertices? Because it doesn't happen that way. I'm, by the way, curious how to achieve that. Could use array on curve, but it doesn't work perfect either.